# Google Identity Services: initCodeClient().requestCode() prompts user signin even though token is valid

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity

After obtaining authorization token:

```
    const tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
       client_id, scope, callback, 
    });
            
    // ...
    
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: ''})
```

I need to obtain authorization code and send it to backend:

```
    let code;

    const codeClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
        scope, client_id, 
        callback: codeResponse => code = codeResponse.code,
    });

    codeClient.requestCode();
```

Despite the user has authorized once, and `gapi.client.getToken()` is not `null` **the popup window appears another time**.

Is there any solution to avoid redundant user authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's because user's consent on obtaining token (`initTokenClient`) does not automatically mean consent on obtaining authorization code (`initCodeClient`).
You can obtain authorization code and translate it to a token in backend which could be then used in frontend as `gapi.client.setToken(token)` if the scope matches.